# LazyVGrid .fixed argument is not filled

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 4 buttons and want them to be all the same width event if buttons content is `"123123"` or `"2"` I want all of their width to be the same I added `.fixed(100)` in my `GridItem` array but it doesnt seem to work

here's the photo where you can see the widths are different

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var num1:Int = 0
    var num2:Int = 0
    var privateGridLayout = [GridItem(.fixed(100)),GridItem(.fixed(100))]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                
            }
            LazyVGrid(columns: privateGridLayout, spacing: 10) {
                BB(content: "AC", value: 1)
                BB(content: "TE", value: 1)
                BB(content: "%", value: 1)
                BB(content: "%", value: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct BB:View {
    var content:String
    var value:Int
    var body:some View{
        Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
            Text(content)
        }.padding()
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .frame(minWidth: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, maxWidth: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.infinity/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, minHeight: 50)
        .font(.system(size:40))
        .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did the `/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/` come from? They make the code very hard to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by moving `background` modifier after `frame`. When it's placed before, it only applied to content size, but not to the "filled" size. Check out [Why modifier order matters](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-modifier-order-matters)

```
struct BB:View {
    var content:String
    var value:Int
    var body:some View{
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text(content)
        }.padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .font(.system(size:40))
            .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this in BB:

```
Text(content).frame(width: 100, height: 50)
```

or

```
Text("\(value)").frame(width: 100, height: 50)
```